# Problems with correlated update in oracle SQL

Tags: database, oracle, sql-update

My question would be a little too long so:

### TL;DR

Oracle correlated update doesn't work as expected, leaving victim column without changes.

### Tables structure

STUDENTS:

```
STUDENT_ID  NUMBER(5,0)         
LAST_NAME   VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)   
FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)   
MIDDLE_NAME     VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)   
FINANCIAL_AID   NUMBER(7,2) 
CLASS_NO    VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)       
SPECIALITY      VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
```

CLASSES:

```
CLASS_NO    VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)   
SPECIALITY_NO   NUMBER(5,0)
```

SPECIALITIES:

```
SPECIALITY_ID   NUMBER(5,0)
SPECIALITY_NAME VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
```

### Task

Basicaly, I need to augment STUDENTS table's column SPECIALITY with SPECIALITY_NAME values (right now it's populated with `null`s) which I can get via connecting with CLASSES and SPECIALITIES tables (yep, I know that's weird and will broke database normalization, but that's the task).

So here is what I'm trying to do:

```
UPDATE STUDENTS S SET SPECIALITY = (SELECT SPECIALITY_NAME FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM STUDENTS NATURAL JOIN
    CLASSES NATURAL JOIN SPECIALITIES) ALLS
  WHERE S.STUDENT_ID = ALLS.STUDENT_ID)
```

### Problem

Oracle says that *N rows updated.*, hence query result seems to be ok, but SPECIALITY column in STUDENTS table still contains only nulls.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
update students s set specialty = 
   (select sp.specialty_name from classes c
    join specialities sp
      on sp.speciality_number = c.speciality_number
    where c.class_no = s.class_no)
```